# Where does $\frac {\pi}{4}$ come from in this inverse sine graph? $y=-3\sin\frac {x\pi}{4})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I understand that the vertical shift is $0$ that is why the graph starts at $(0,0)$. Also I understand that the amplitude is $3$ because the maximum y value is $3$ and the minimum y value is $-3$. Last but not least the graph is inverse sine but it seems to be a period and a half. I am not sure where the  $\frac {\pi}{4}$ comes from. I need help understanding that part. Photo of problem attached below. Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmX41.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = \sin(x)$ gets a value $1$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$ \Rightarrow y = -3\sin(x)$ gets a value $-3$ at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$ \Rightarrow y = -3\sin(ax)$ gets a value $-3$ at $ax=\frac{\pi}{2}$

We have $y=-3$ at $x = 2$.
So, $ax = \frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow 2a = \frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow\boxed{a = \frac{1}{4}\pi}$

The equation is $\boxed{ y = -3\sin(ax)=-3\sin\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi x\right)}$

Comment: Great this helps a lot. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a sine curve is

$$ y = A \sin \dfrac{2 \pi x}{\lambda}$$

So in your particular case amplitude and wavelengths are

$$A=-3, \lambda= 8$$

Your graph is negative in start amplitude compared to standard sine of positive initial slope, but is not an inverse sine graph. Inverse graphs have $(x,y)$ axes interchanged.

Comment: How did you get 8 for the wavelength?

Comment: The correct form is $\sin \frac{2\pi x}{\lambda}$ with $2 \pi$ in the numerator so that $\sin$ should vanish in argument when $x=\lambda$. In your argument we should multiply numerator and denominator each by 2 and look at the denominator to find out $\lambda =8.$

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped you.